# How to check for multiple data when deleting a row

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I want to delete a row using Python with MySQL but when I delete it I have to use this command:

```
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE username= jazzar")
```

But I want to check for multiple things like the email and password

Comment: Are you storing password in the clear?  Or is it a salted hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple conditions in query.

```
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE username = jazzar AND email = jazzar@example.com AND password = YOUR_PASSWORD")
```